# Spark 2.2.1 read log4.xml from resources in fat-jar

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, log4j

I am running spark locally on my machine and I want to load the log4.xml file from the resources.

The command I run is

```
spark-submit --class spark.MyClass --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=1g \
--conf spark.driver.memory=26g --conf spark.executor.memory=26g \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dlog4j.configuration=log/log4j.xml -Dlog4j.debug" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dlog4j.configuration=log/log4j.xml -Dlog4j.debug" \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=100 \
./build/libs/my-fat.jar


log4j: Trying to find [log/log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cf4f579.
log4j: Trying to find [log/log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cf4f579 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log/log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [log/log4j.xml].
```

All the class does is to read from the resources the log4j.xml file and print it.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val resource: InputStream =this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("log/log4j.xml")
    val lines=Source.fromInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(resource)).getLines().toList
     lines.foreach(l=>println(l))

}
```

The file is printed, but the log4j.xml file is not found by log4j.

Is there a way to load the log4j.xml file from the resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had the same problem I solved it by reading log4j config from resources in the beginning of my application:

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("log/log4j.xml"))
```